# How to conduct a post-hoc test to determine whether a specific level of a factor differs from a default value (after controlling for other variables)?

Tags: statistical-significance, post-hoc, lsmeans

Here is the code of the "Orange sales" example in the lsmeans package

```
library("lsmeans")
oranges.lm1 <- lm(sales1 ~ price1 + price2 + day + store, data = oranges)
anova(oranges.lm1)
lsmeans(oranges.lm1, ~ day)
plot(lsmeans(oranges.lm1, ~ day))
```

I would like to know whether there is a specific post-hoc test to assess whether the sales on Day 1 are significantly lower than 10 (or whether the sales on Day 3 at Store 6 are significantly higher than 10), with an associated p-value, while controlling for all the other effects?

Or is it enough to simply look at the output of `lsmeans(oranges.lm1, ~ day)` and realize that for Day 1, the interval between lower.CL and upper.CL does not contain 10 (or that for Day 3 at Store 6 (obtained by `lsmeans(oranges.lm1, ~ day | store)`), the interval between lower.CL and upper.CL also does not contain 10)?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
test(lsmeans(oranges.lm1, ~ day | store), null = 10)
```